# Unable to upload media files: Maximum upload file size: 0 B

Tags: media-library

All of sudden I am seeing the above. `php.ini` already have the following lines:

```
post_max_size = 1024M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
```

Answer (score 1):

Check folder permissions for wp-content/upload. It should be set to 755 or 775.